# 'Texture unit out of range error' in three.js breaks app?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to use sparks.js in my app via the THREEx.Sparks module that Jerome made for his [live sparks editor](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/sparkseditor). However it only works with three.js up to and including r50 - after which the sparks trail never gets rendered.

I have put up a (somewhat) minimal [fork](https://github.com/themasterchef/sparksjs-dev) of the editor for all to play with. The cylinder always gets drawn, but as we step up through the three.js revisions:

- r46 works, but is of course now very outdated
- r50 and r49 draw the particles as expected, but with this WebGL error: `WebGL: INVALID_ENUM: activeTexture: texture unit out of range`
- starting at r51, the particle system of the sparks is not drawn

The error is quite likely to do with how THREE handles improperly initialised textures. I have chased it down to the 128x128 radial texture created in `_buildDefaultTexture` inside `THREEx.Sparks.js`.

The reason this is a SO question (and not a GH bug report) is that THREE r51+ have evidently got the right error handling - they don't even attempt the bad behaviour because that makes WebGL a sad panda, whereas r50 and down just did it anyway and caused errors. My question is:

- **what** exactly is `THREEx.Sparks.js` not doing properly here
- and **why** did it kinda still work prior to r51

System info: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17 | WebGL 1.0 (OpenGL ES 2.0 Chromium) | WebKit | WebKit WebGL | WebGL GLSL ES 1.0 (OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0 Chromium)

Screenshot of sparksjs-dev in action using r50 available for your viewing pleasure at i.stack.imgur.com/p5EfN.png (if it hasn't been pulled yet), which shows the bungled `uniform1i` and `activeTexture` calls in the WebGL debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to debug your code for you, but I can definitely point you in the right direction.

First, see the [Migration Wiki](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) for help upgrading to the current version.

For example, you will see that in THREEx.Sparks.js,

```
texture : { type: "t", texture: this._texture }
```

should now be

```
texture : { type: "t", value: this._texture }
```

There may be other issues.

I can't comment on old versions of three.js, only the current one.

three.js r.55

Comment: That one line was the kicker, together with a couple of other fixes it works in r55 now. I'll try to submit the fixed version as a pull request. Thanks!